# MySQL Constrain Error 1452

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project that worksa with java and MySQL.
My question is about the MySQL part.

I'm working on a database and i'm trying to test everything but i can't implementate any data.

I get all the time an error:
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails(`poker`.`inschrijving`.CONSTRAIN `inschrijving_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY(`Lid`)REFERENCES `toernooi`(`Tid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

This is my Database:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS poker;
USE poker;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Locatie;
CREATE TABLE Locatie (
Lid int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Lnaam Varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Ladress varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Lopp double,
PRIMARY KEY (Lid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Locatie` (`Lid`,`Lnaam`,`Ladress`,`Lopp`) VALUES 
(10000001,'Grote zaal Den Bos','Lange weg 34, Den Bos',54.5),
(10000002,'Casino Vlaardingen','Achterbaan 119, Vlaardingen',2500.5),
(10000003,'Homerson Casino','Oxfordstraat 19, Zoetermeer',1000),
(10000004,'Van der valk casino','Dorpsweg 45, Sasseheim',9899);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Speler;
CREATE TABLE Speler (
Sid int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Snaam varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Se_mail varchar(80) NOT NULL,
Sadress varchar(40) NOT NULL,
Swoonplaats varchar(35) NOT NULL,
Spostcode varchar(6) NOT NULL,
Stelnr int(19) NOT NULL,
Sgesl ENUM('M', 'F'),
Sgbd date NOT NULL,
Srating int(10) NOT NULL,
Sgewonnen_geld double NOT NULL,
Sbekende_speler boolean,
PRIMARY KEY (Sid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Speler` (`Sid`,`Snaam`,`Se_mail`,`Sadress`,`Swoonplaats`,`Spostcode`,`Stelnr`,`Sgesl`,`Sgbd`,`Srating`,`Sgewonnen_geld`,`Sbekende_speler`) VALUES 
(20000003,'Jan Peter','Jpeter@gmail.com','Scherium weg 20','Den bos','2123IE',062586475,'M','1983-05-18',1250,209.00,False),
(20000001,'Roy Henson','Roy.Henson@telfort.nl','Shindori straat 231','Leiden','3212IO',0623568974,'M','1986-08-21',700,2310.00,True),
(20000009,'Willium Ransom','WilRan@hotmail.com','Hooftweg 521','Groningen','1251UI',0623541289,'M','1979-04-29',1250,20315.00,True),
(20000002,'Rhindia Rosenberg','RhindiaR@gmail.com','Dorpstraat 210','Den Haag','2621',0622775412,'F','1990-11-21',275,10321.00,False);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Toernooi;
CREATE TABLE Toernooi (
Tid int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Tnaam varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Tmax_speler int(5) NOT NULL,
Tinleggeld double NOT NULL,
Ttype varchar(25) NOT NULL,
Tdatum datetime NOT NULL,
Lid int(12) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Tid),
FOREIGN KEY (Lid) REFERENCES Locatie (Lid)
ON DELETE RESTRICT
ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Toernooi` (`Tid`,`Tnaam`,`Tmax_speler`,`Tinleggeld`,`Ttype`,`Tdatum`,`Lid`) VALUES 
(30000001,'MCi',340,75.00,'Professional','2012-06-21 19:00:00',10000002),
(30000002,'chaos',200,150.00,'Professional','2012-07-15 21:00:00',10000003),
(30000003,'Homerson!',400,45,'Amatuer','2012-08-25 20:30:00',10000001),
(30000004,'Valkerin',1000,20,'Amatuer','2012-09-01 23:59:59',10000004);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MasterClass;
CREATE TABLE MasterClass (
Mid int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Mmin_rating int(10) NOT NULL,
Mmax_spelers int(3) NOT NULL,
Mniveau varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Mdatum datetime NOT NULL,
Sid int(12) NOT NULL,
Lid int(12) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (mid),
FOREIGN KEY (Lid) REFERENCES Locatie (Lid)
ON DELETE RESTRICT
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (Sid) REFERENCES Speler (Sid)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `MasterClass` (`Mid`,`Mmin_rating`,`Mmax_spelers`,`Mniveau`,`Mdatum`,`Sid`,`Lid`) VALUES 
(40000001,1100,50,'Professional','2012-05-21 22:00:00',20000009,10000001),
(40000002,3500,120,'Amateur','2012-09-07 15:00:00',20000001,10000002);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Status;
CREATE TABLE Status (
Tid int(12) NOT NULL,
Sid int(12) NOT NULL,
ronde varchar(25) NOT NULL,
tafel int(3) NOT NULL,
winst double NOT NULL,
startrating int(10) NOT NULL,
eindrating int(10) NOT NULL,
plaats int(5) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Tid,Sid),
FOREIGN KEY (Tid) REFERENCES Toernooi (Tid)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (Sid) REFERENCES Speler (Sid)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Status` (`Tid`,`Sid`,`ronde`,`tafel`,`winst`,`startrating`,`eindrating`)    VALUES 
(30000004,20000003,20,5,0.00,800,700),
(30000004,20000001,12,2,0.00,750,600),
(30000004,20000002,4,19,6700.00,1000,1250),
(30000004,20000009,9,12,3400.00,250,275);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Inschrijving;
CREATE TABLE Inschrijving (
Iid int(12) NOT NULL,
Sid int(12) NOT NULL,
Ibetaald boolean,
PRIMARY KEY  (Iid,Sid),
FOREIGN KEY (Iid) REFERENCES Toernooi (Tid)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (Iid) REFERENCES MasterClass (Mid)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (Sid) REFERENCES Speler (Sid)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Inschrijving` (`Iid`,`Sid`,`Ibetaald`) VALUES 
(40000001,20000003,true), //Its goes wrong here!!! This is where the error come
(40000002,20000002,false),
(30000003,20000001,true),
(30000004,20000009,false);
```

I hope someone can help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an interesting foreign key structure: the Iid points to two tables at the same time. When you add a new Inschrijving.Iint, there must be rows with the same Iid values in **both** referenced tables!

```
CREATE TABLE Inschrijving (
Iid int(12) NOT NULL,
!!
FOREIGN KEY (Iid) REFERENCES Toernooi    (Tid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (Iid) REFERENCES MasterClass (Mid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

Comment: So in other words there must a Tid and a Mid with the same value Exp: Iid=1 then Mid=1 and Tid=1 right?

Comment: Yes, I think, MySQL should check all constraints independently, and if one fails, the whole operation fails.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign keys

```
FOREIGN KEY (Iid) REFERENCES Toernooi (Tid)
FOREIGN KEY (Iid) REFERENCES MasterClass (Mid)
```

in your table defintion of Inschrijving seems to reference the wrong field or the wrong table. There is already a foreign key for Iid. And those references make no sense semantically, too.